# CPU usage explodes from 30-40% to 99%?

Tags: cpu, browser, cpu-usage, opera

Whenever I try to browse `www.upstox.com` in `Opera 65` or any other browser, suddenly CPU usage explodes to `99%`, GPU usage explodes to `>80%`, fan starts to throw  fire at me.

Meanwhile, this service called `Sysadmin` starts and it explodes disk usage to 80%.

Now, this happens all the time, when I try to access the site. Is this a sign to cryptomining or something else. Because I didn't see the `Cryptograpy` service running.

What does this mean?

Comment: Opera Browser  is build upon the Chomium engine, and as such should somewhere have a taskmanager inside to showcase what exactly is using all your CPU time and memory. Access it to get more information of what is eating up CPU time.

Comment: It appears to be a stock trading platform and may be trying to install something. Is that the only site causing excess CPU? Do not use it if that is the case.

Comment: @John Yes! This is the only site that causes this problem. But this is not the case when my friend opens it in chrome.

Comment: So there is nothing wrong - just a site problem

Comment: Best bet is to install the ADK/WDK and install Windows Performance Toolkit.  Then create a first level triage trace of the problem with Windows Performance Recorder.  Then open this trace file up in Windows Perormance Analyzer (WPR) and see where the CPU/Disk usage is coming from.